# C++ Builder TThread class and collection items manipulations

Tags: c++, c++builder, tthread

I wonder if my source code is well designed?

In the main thread, I declare and use a collection. To fill this collection, a long processing is necessary, and I want to do this processing in a secondary thread.

So, I create a thread using the `TThread` class proposed by C++Builder. In the constructor of this class, I pass a pointer to my collection, and the `Execute()` function of the thread uses this pointer to feed the collection.

I specify that the collection is not used at all during this processing.

Is this the right way to do this?

threadconfig.h

```
class TThreadGetConfig : public TThread
{
private:
    pSDK FSDK;
    pControllersCollection FSubControllers;

protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();

public:
    __fastcall TThreadGetConfig(pSDK paramSDK, pControllersCollection paramSubControllers);
};
```

threadconfig.cpp

```
__fastcall TThreadGetConfig::TThreadGetConfig(pSDK paramSDK, pControllersCollection paramSubControllers)
: TThread(true)
{
    FSDK = paramSDK;
    FSubControllers = paramSubControllers;

    FreeOnTerminate = true;
}

void __fastcall TThreadGetConfig::Execute()
{
    ReturnValue = (GetSiteConfig() ? 0:1);
    Terminate();
}

bool __fastcall TThreadGetConfig::GetSiteConfig()
{
    std::vector<TSDK_ConfigData>::iterator ptr_subctrl;
   ...

    try
    {
        if (!SDK->Connected)
            throw Exception("sdk error");

        //get data from sdk calls
        ...

        for (ptr_subctrl = subcontrollers.begin(); ptr_subctrl < subcontrollers.end(); ptr_subctrl++)
        {
            pControllerItem subctrl_item = (pControllerItem)SubControllers->Add();
            subctrl_item->Data->Id = ptr_subctrl->id;
            subctrl_item->Data->Serial = ptr_subctrl->serial;
            ...
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }

    return false;
}
```

main.h

```
class TfrmMain : public TForm
{
__published:
   ...
private:
   TThreadGetConfig *thrdGetConfig;
    pSDK FSDK;
    pControllersCollection FSubControllers;
}
```

main.cpp

```
__fastcall TfrmMain::TfrmMain(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    FSubControllers = new TControllersCollection(NULL);
    FSDK = new TSDK();
}

void __fastcall TfrmMain::StartThread()
{
    thrdGetConfig = new TThreadGetConfig(
            this->SDK,
            this->SubControllers);

    thrdGetConfig->Resume();
}
```

Comment: This is rather vague. For instance, what does "I specify that the collection is not used" mean? If you share more context and details, people might be able to answer your question better.

Comment: "The collection is not used" means that it's not read or written during process.
Main thread waits for secondary thread end before analysing collection content

Comment: "*I wonder if my source code is well designed?*" - you didn't show your actual code, so nobody can answer that.

Comment: Hi Remy,
I'm just talking about the concept of manipulating directly in a secondary thread the items of a collection whose instance was created in the main thread. I've tried it and it works but I wonder if it's really thread-safe.
If I have to show my code so that someone can help me answer this question, I'll gladly do so

Comment: @remy-lebeau Code added ;)

Comment: @Engi Filling the collection in a worker thread is fine, as long as the collection API has no thread affinity, and no other threads use the collection without synchronization. In any case, you say "*I specify that the collection is not used at all during this processing*", but the code you have shown doesn't guarantee that. For instance, when the main thread wants to use the collection, it could first check if `thrdGetConfig` is NULL, indicating the thread is not running. You can use the `TThreadGetConfig::OnTerminate` event to set `thrdGetConfig` to NULL when the thread is finished.